# How to get Timezone offset from moment Object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I have `moment` Object defined as:

```
var moment = require('moment');

moment('2015-12-20T12:00:00+02:00');
```

When I print it, I get:

```
_d: Sun Dec 20 2015 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)
_f: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ"
_i: "2015-12-20T12:00:00+02:00"
_isAMomentObject: true
_isUTC: false
_locale: r
_pf: Object
_tzm: 120
```

How to fetch by right way `_tzm`? (suppose its offset in minutes)

Thanks,

Comment: moment().utcOffset() ?

Comment: `moment.tz.guess();` for latest built

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just access the property like you would in any object

```js
var result = moment('2015-12-20T12:00:00+02:00');


document.body.innerHTML = result._tzm;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Another option would be to parse the date and get the zone

```
moment.parseZone('2015-12-20T12:00:00+02:00').utcOffset(); // 120
// or
moment().utcOffset('2015-12-20T12:00:00+02:00')._offset; // 120
```

Comment: if you need offset for **angular**'s `date`  pipe you can use `momentObject.format('Z')` which returns for example -08:00