# Date.prototype.setMonth() changes the timezone offset?

Tags: javascript

This only occurs with the `setMonth()` method and none of the other `set*()` methods.

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
var date = new Date();
date.getTimezoneOffset(); // -60

date.setMonth(5);
date.getTimezoneOffset(); // -120
```

Is this expected behavior? [There's nothing mentioned about this on MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth)

Comment: You may be crossing a daylight saving boundary.

Comment: Using the raw Javascript date code is a recipe for disaster.  Moment.js is the industry standard, but there are also other good date libraries.  You would be far better served using Moment or another library rather than trying to use the basic JS date stuff, as it has numerous problems.

Comment: @machineghost—that is a very dark view that can't be substantiated. Moment.js does not help the OP with this issue.

Comment: JavaScript goes out of its way to handle UTC offsets incorrectly. This is in the standard. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.8

Comment: @RobG it may be dark, but it's a view shared by many experienced JS developers; just Google something like "why use moment" and you'll see a wealth of pages saying something to the effect of "native JS date parsing isn't the worst thing in the world, but Moment is a lot better."  As for Moment.js not helping the OP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34838542/how-to-get-timezone-offset-from-moment-object

Comment: @machineghost—I agree that ECMAScript date parsing and formatting is broken to the extent that I always advise alternatives be used, but this question is about the timezone offset and daylight saving. The solution in your linked question is equivalent to `-date.getTimezoneOffset()`, which is less to type and does need a large library. All libraries I know of still use the built–in Date, so it's not *that* broken. ;-) BTW, the OP's offsets seem inconsistent: the sign indicates they're east of Greenwich but the change in magnitude indicates they're west.

Comment: Right, so you can learn one API (the base JS date API), and use it for some date/time problems, and then you can learn a whole different API (eg. Moment) for doing all other date/time logic.  Of course, to even be able to say "this problem is best solved using API X", you need to learn and understand both APIs very well.  So your options are learn two APIs, well enough to know when to use one or the other ... OR you can just learn and use a single API (eg. Moment) for *all* date-related logic.  For most devs, the latter is the easier/better approach, which is why I advocate it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`getTimezoneOffset` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) returns a different value during DST, and in month `5` the `DST` is different than now.

> The time zone offset returned is the one that applies for the Date that it's called on. Where the host system is configured for daylight saving, the offset will change depending on the date and time that the Date represents and that daylight saving applies.

```js
var date = new Date();
console.log(date.getTimezoneOffset());

date.setMonth(0);
console.log(date.getTimezoneOffset());

date.setMonth(5);
console.log(date.getTimezoneOffset());
```

btw, if you will run this code during June - you will see that there is no difference :)

Comment: Also, if the host is not set to observe daylight saving, there's no difference now either. ;-)