# How to Get TimeZoneOffset From Moment

Tags: momentjs, angular2-template, angular-moment

I am using Moment in my project now using same Moment i want to get the timezoneoffset.

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

I am passing the TimeZone

> Europe/Oslo

i want to get the Offset. Please help if somebody done this.

Comment: Are you looking for [`utcOffset()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/)? What you tried so far? Which is your issue?

Comment: You can't get an offset without an actual date. There are daylight savings and other considerations which require a date to be passed as input as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Timezone offset from moment Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34838542/how-to-get-timezone-offset-from-moment-object)